# Subtract amount from cart

Tags: cart, quote, discount, cart-rule

For a special project we need to be able to subtract a variable amount from the cart totals. I couldn't really find an example which does that as well.

As far as I know, I know that cart discount is only available by applying a coupon code.

My idea would be to generate a temporary coupon code with the specified discount price, apply it to the cart and remove it after checkout.

Obviously this doesn't sound like the method to do this, but I can't really think of another method.

Does anyone have a better idea or could someone guide me into a certain direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento's Catalog Price Rules to do this without needing to use a coupon code.

Here's a quick tutorial that should help: http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/catalog-price-rules